# How to handle "Done" return key press event in rxSwift?

Tags: swift2, reactive-programming, rx-swift

While exploring [RxSwift](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift)

I found just `textField.rx_text.asObservable()` property, that fires event every keyboard button is hit.

But how do we handle "search" or "done" button press events? I'd like to fire search only after these actions, not "search as you type".

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You can subscribe to UIControlEvents like this:

`textField.rx_controlEvents(.EditingDidEndOnExit).subscribeNext {
  print("return pressed")
}`

Comment: Is it possible to wrap it as an observable?

Comment: Yes, try this:

`textField.rx_controlEvents(.EditingDidEndOnExit).asObservable()`

Comment: most important question is how to NOT dismiss keyboard on subscribing to this controlEvent

Comment: This actually creates contradiction when you want to resign keyboard if tap outside of textfield. Both the scenario ends up observed and creates unexpected behaviour.

Answer (score 23):

In RxSwift 4 and 5:

```
textField.rx.controlEvent([.editingDidEndOnExit]).subscribe { _ in
    print("editingDidEndOnExit")
}.disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

Comment: No need to add brackets around `.editingDidEndOnExit`

Comment: What `print(text)` suppose to print, initially I thought it would be the text from the text field but when I tried it prints out empty bracket ()

Comment: @koira good point. "text" should have been named "event". but it does not contain valuable information so I removed it to prohibit confusion.

Answer (score 6):

In **Rxswift 3.0**

```
textField.rx.controlEvent([.editingDidEndOnExit])
         .subscribe(onNext:{text in
            print(text)
         }).addDisposableTo(disposeBag)
```

Comment: `.disposed(by: disposeBag)` ** 
`addDisposableTo` is on the way to deprecation.